# If statement reads false even though it's true

Tags: if-statement, velo

```
//Variable Set
let currentstateB;

$w("#backb3").onClick(() => {
     if (currentstateB === $w('#Phone')) {
                //True
        $w("#FormBox").changeState("Phone");
    } else {
                //False
        console.log("Error");
    }
})

//Save previous state to variable.
$w("#nextb1").onClick(() => {
    let currentstateB = $w("#FormBox").currentState;
    console.log(currentstateB);
})
```

## No matter what I do the if statement reads false even though the console.log(currentstateB) prints $w('#Phone')

I obtained what Velo sees when it saves the current state of the Multi State Box when the back button three is clicked. Console.log(currentstateB) prints $w('#Phone')
Now when I take what it prints and put it within the if statement the if statement always say that the variable currentstateB IS NOT $w('#Phone') but HOW??? the variable was just set to and printed $w('#Phone')

Besides the problem I am trying to achieve a form of some sort. I would like for the program to capture the current state of the Multi State Box depending on which next button is clicked and store that within currentstateB; If the user decides to go back to the previous page then the state that was captured within the variable currentstateB is which page the user will go back to.

See what I'm trying to do here??? if not I'm trying to have the program recognize which page the user was previously on and go back to that page when the back button is clicked.